# Custom filter with dropdown to grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

here is the HTML page which i am working with,it's not working properly.
where is the issue can any one check it once.

here issue after the filter the grid the drop down value also changing or filtering.

can  Any one check this code in html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link  href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">



    <span class="nwcselection">data</span>
    <input id="ddl"/></div>
<input type="button" id="btnfilter" value="Filter" onclick="Filter()" />
<div id="grid"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var data =new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read:
                    "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
        },
    });
    function createGrid()
    {
        var grid= $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:data,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        ProductID: { type: "number" },
                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                    } }},

            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "ProductID", title:"Product ID", width:100 },
                { field: "ProductName", title:"Product Name" },
                { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", width: 100 } ]
        });
    }






    function dd()
    {
        $("#ddl").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: data,
            optionLabel: "Select category...",
            dataTextField: "ProductName",
            dataValueField: "ProductName"
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
    }


    function Filter() {

        $("#btnfilter").click(function () {
            $filter = new Array();
            $ProductName = $("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList").value();

            if($ProductName)
            {
                $filter.push({ field: "ProductName",
                    operator: "contains", value: $ProductName });
            }
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

            grid.dataSource.filter({
                logic: "and",
                filters: $filter
            });
        });

    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

        createGrid();
        Filter();
        dd();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same DataSource for the Grid and the DropDown: they are like pointers to the same object. Filtering one will filter the other because they are actually the same thing.

Try creating the DataSource twice:

```
var ds1 =new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read:
                "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
    }
});
var ds2 =new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read:
                "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
    }
});
```

and then use each of them in a different element:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds1,
    schema    : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                ProductID  : { type: "number" },
                UnitPrice  : { type: "number" },
                ProductName: { type: "string" }
            } }},

    pageable: true,
    columns : [
        { field: "ProductID", title: "Product ID", width: 100 },
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", width: 100 }
    ]
});

$("#ddl").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource    : ds2,
    optionLabel   : "Select category...",
    dataTextField : "ProductName",
    dataValueField: "ProductName"
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```